# Deploy ember gives UnrecognizedURLError

Tags: ember.js

I compile my app for production mode with this command:

```
sudo ember build --environment=production
```

Then I copy the contents of the dist map into a map in filezilla.

When I go to subdomain.domain.eu/myRoute/44444, I get:

> Uncaught UnrecognizedURLError

When I go to subdomain.domain.eu/index.html, the app loads but I need the 44444 from the urlin my app as a param.

How does this come and what is the solution?

My .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html#$1 [L]
```

Building for development and production produces the same results.
The current error I'm getting is 500 internal server error.

Comment: Might be a problem with your .htaccess file, attach it, please

Comment: I have included it

Comment: Would you mind building for development and deploying that to see if you get a different error in your console?

Comment: I'm more familiar with nginx, but I don't think your .htaccess is set up correctly. If you have some newer version of Ember and didn't explicitly opt out, you won't probably be using #-based routes. I think your rewrite rule should be "RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html [PT,QSA]" (PT doesn't change the URL in the browser which is important for ember and QSA keeps any query string). Other people, please correct this, if it's wrong.

Comment: Fryie, your answer works, make an answer out of it and I'll accept it as the correct answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're (very probably, unless you're using an old Ember version or explicitly enabled this) not using hash-based URLs, your rewrite rule should probably look like:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html [PT,QSA]
```

The PT is needed to not change the URL and the QSA keeps any appended query strings around.
Apparently, [PT is apparently the default anyway for .htaccess files](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/flags.html#flag_pt) but it cannot hurt to make that explicit.

The reasoning is that you want Apache to *not* care about your URL and serve the index.html for everything. But since Ember needs the original URL to recognise what route it should serve, the URL needs to be unchanged as far as the client is concerned.